# Is font-face as div background image possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to use fontfaces as icons for my buttons and divs, unfortunately the fontface rendering is not consistent across browsers so pixel-perfect sizing is very difficult to achieve. I was wondering whether it would be possible to somehow assign a fontface as a background image of a div.

Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: For something you need so pixel perfect that regular css fonts wont do.. Just use a picture?

Comment: Maybe you can render text using that font-face into a canvas, grab the picture from it as a base64 png, and then set that as background image for the DIV. But thats a lot of work. Unless this is absolutely critical, it might be better to just use an image.

Comment: "_rendering is not consistent across browsers_", which browser mainly? chrome? if so, declare the `src` to svg font type before the others

Comment: @techfoobar: Rendering of text into a canvas will most likely happen using the same mechanism that is used to render “normal” text in a document, so it will show the same differences across browsers …

Comment: @CBroe - True. So thats a non-alternative. I guess using an image is indeed the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `z-index` and `absolute` positioning. How about this-

http://jsfiddle.net/PaeLD/